# GeoTools 12.3 creating shapefile from coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers, java, geotools

I want to export a vector layer to a shapefile (create a zip file with .dbf, .fix. prj and .shp), but when the exported .shp file is opened in a Desktop GIS it doesn't show anything. For the exporting process I'm taking the vector's geometry from the client's side and then passing it to GeoTools.

Example of coordinates taken:

```
POLYGON((-73.66493725746473 10.990018872870637,-73.66491744931622 10.989778575306673,-73.66461659312377 10.989083441330243,-73.66432392645686 10.988671614711865,-73.66385054708721 10.988174381001494,-73.6636295847281 10.987926762071364,-73.66354307873837 10.98763623506447,-73.66344985681403 10.987231733013479,-73.66330765326558 10.986516057447549,-73.66310202963504 10.985865278941809,.....))
```

Here I take the geometry of the vector:

```
        ...
        {
            var featureGeom = [];
            var arreglo = [];
            var arreglo2 = [];

            var controlador = aplicacion.getController("ControlResultados");        
            var vectorSeleccion = controlador.buscarcapa('capaSeleccion').getSource().getFeatures();

            for (var x = 0; x < vectorSeleccion.length; x++) {
                featureGeom.push(vectorSeleccion[x].getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                for (var y = 0; y < featureGeom[x][0].length; y++) {
                    arreglo.push(featureGeom[x][0][y]);
                }
            }

            for (var z = 0; z < arreglo.length; z++) {
                arreglo2.push(arreglo[z][0]+" "+arreglo[z][1]);
            }

            var nombreArchivo = "archivoSHPResultado";
            var parametros = {
                    archivoPersistencia : nombreArchivo,
                    geomPolygon : "POLYGON(("+arreglo2.toString()+"))",
                    nombreArchivo: 'CapaSHPResultado'
            };
            this.descargaArchivoSHP(parametros);
        },
        descargaArchivoSHP: function(contenido){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url : "ServletShape",
                method : 'POST',
                params : contenido,
                success : function( respuesta ) {
                    var rutaActual = location.href.split("//");
                    var rutaActualPartes = rutaActual[1].split("/");
                    var nuevaRuta = rutaActual[0] + "//" + rutaActualPartes[0] + "/" + rutaActualPartes[1] + "/" + respuesta.responseText;

                    window.open(nuevaRuta);

                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'WARN',
                        msg: 'OK',
                        buttonText: {
                            yes: 'OK',
                        }
                    });
                },
                failure : function() {

                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'WARN',
                        msg: 'FAIL',
                        buttonText: {
                            yes: 'OK',
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
}
...
```

Here is the Java class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction;
import org.geotools.data.Transaction;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

import utilidades.utilidadesGeometriaGeotools;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

public class BBShape {

private static final int BUFFER = 4096;
private String rutaPersistencia = null; 
private String nombreArchivoZip = null;
private String nombreXlsSalida = null;

public String getRutaPersistencia() {
    return rutaPersistencia;
}

public void setRutaPersistencia(String rutaPersistencia) {
    this.rutaPersistencia = rutaPersistencia;
}

public String getNombreArchivoZip() {
    return nombreArchivoZip;
}

public void setNombreArchivoZip(String nombreArchivoZip) {
    this.nombreArchivoZip = nombreArchivoZip;
}

public void Exportar(String nombreShape, String tipoShape, String geomShape, String separador){

    try {

        String pathArchivo = rutaPersistencia + nombreShape + ".shp";

        SimpleFeatureType featureType =  DataUtilities.createType( tipoShape,  "location:" + tipoShape + ":srid=4326," + "number:Integer");

        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal",featureType);

        String[] geomArray = geomShape.split(separador);

        for (int i = 0; i < geomArray.length; i++) {
            Geometry geometria = utilidadesGeometriaGeotools.WKTgeometriaLectura(geomArray[i]);
            featureCollection.add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( featureType, new Object[]{ geometria, 2}, null) );
        }

        File file = new File(pathArchivo);  

        ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        params.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
        params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

        ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
        newDataStore.createSchema(featureType);
        newDataStore.forceSchemaCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

        Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

        String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

        if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

            featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
            try {
                featureStore.addFeatures(featureCollection);
                transaction.commit();

            } catch (Exception problem) {
                problem.printStackTrace();
                transaction.rollback();

            } finally {
                transaction.close();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(typeName + " No se peude acceder");
        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {

    }   
}

public void deleteFolderContent(File folder){
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    if(files!=null)
        for(File f: files)
            if(f.isDirectory()) deleteFolderContent(f);
            else f.delete();
}

public String zipDirectorio() {

    String pathCarpeta= rutaPersistencia;
    String pathArchivo = pathCarpeta + nombreArchivoZip + ".zip";

    File d = new File(pathCarpeta);
    if (!d.isDirectory())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(pathCarpeta + " no es un directorio." );
    String[] entries = d.list();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
    int bytesRead;

    try {
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathArchivo));

        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            File f = new File(d, entries[i]);

            if (f.isDirectory())
                continue; 

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entries[i]);
            out.putNextEntry(entry);

            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            in.close();
        }
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    nombreXlsSalida = this.getNombreArchivoZip() + ".zip";

    return (nombreXlsSalida);
}

public String  exportarOpcionesSHP(String pathLogico, String ruta, String geomPolygon, String nombre){

    this.setRutaPersistencia(ruta);

    String strPathFile = "";
    File f=new File(ruta);
    f.mkdir();

    if(f.exists()){
        this.deleteFolderContent(f);

        if (!geomPolygon.equals("")) this.Exportar("poligonos", "Polygon", geomPolygon, "%,");
    }

    this.setNombreArchivoZip(nombre);
    strPathFile = this.zipDirectorio();

    strPathFile = pathLogico + strPathFile;
    return strPathFile;
}   
}
```

Auxiliary class:

```
package utilidades;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTWriter;

public class utilidadesGeometriaGeotools {

static public String WKTgeometria(Geometry geom){

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    WKTWriter wktWriter = new WKTWriter(2);

    try {
        wktWriter.write( geom, writer );
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    String wkt = writer.toString();
    return wkt;
}
static public Geometry WKTgeometriaLectura(String geom){
    Geometry geometria = null;        
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);

    try {
        geometria = (Geometry) reader.read(geom);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geometria;
}

static public LineString  construirLinea (Double xIni,Double yIni,Double xFin,Double yFin ){    
    return  (LineString) WKTgeometriaLectura("LINESTRING("+xIni+" "+yIni+","+ xFin+" "+yFin+")");
}

static public Geometry transformacion(Geometry geom,String sistemaOrigen,String sistemaDestino ){

    Geometry salidaGeometry = null; 
    try {               
        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode(sistemaOrigen);//CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(sistemaDestino); //CRS.decode("EPSG:3116");    
        MathTransform   transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, false);
        salidaGeometry = JTS.transform( geom, transform);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return salidaGeometry;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry column of a ShapeFile **must** be called "the_geom", your's is called "location" so the `ShapefileWriter` ignores it.

change

```
 SimpleFeatureType featureType =  DataUtilities.createType( tipoShape,  "location:" + tipoShape + ":srid=4326," + "number:Integer");
```

to

```
 SimpleFeatureType featureType =  DataUtilities.createType( tipoShape,  "the_geom:" + tipoShape + ":srid=4326," + "number:Integer");
```

and all should be fine.